# g++4.9 not finding method overload in derived class when compiling s-function in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, inheritance

I'm trying to make the following implementation work:

Header of base class:

```
#ifndef BASE_HH
#define BASE_HH

namespace base {
class Agent
{
  public:
    int loop () {return loopImpl();}
  protected:
     virtual int loopImpl() =0;
}
#endif
```

Header or derived class:

```
#ifndef DERIVED_HH
#define DERIVED_HH

#include <base/agent.hh>

namespace derived {
class Agent : public base::Agent
{
  protected:
     virtual int loopImpl();
}
#endif
```

Source file of derived class:

```
#include <derived/agent.hh>

int Agent::loopImpl()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Now, when I compile this in the terminal and test it, it works. But when I try compiling an S-function in Matlab that creates an Agent object, i get the following error:

```
Error using mex 
/path/sfunction.cpp In function ‘void mdlStart(SimStruct*)’:
/path/sfunction.cpp:51:56: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘derived::Agent’
derived::Agent *agent = new derived::Agent ();
/derived_path/agent.hh:28:11: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘derived::Agent’:
class Agent: public base::Agent
In file included from /derived_path/agent.hh:22:0, from /path/sfunction.cpp:13:
/base_path/agent.hh:54:21: note: virtual int base::Agent::loopImpl() virtual int loopImpl () =0;
```

So it seems the g++4.9 compiler is unable to find the derived member function... Could anybody give me some hints on why this is so and what to do about it? As mentioned above, when I compile a similar file creating an object of the same derived class, it works.

Thank you for your time.